# Installing Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 23.10 gives 404 error

Tags: package-management, updates, python, ppa, 23.10

I have recently clean-installed Ubuntu 23.10 after I started getting issues making an upgrade to 23.10 from 23.04. I am trying to install Python 3.7 on my system via ppa:deadsnakies, but it keeps giving me the following error.

```
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu mantic Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here is what I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

I am not trying to replace the default Python version but trying to install it alongside the default version. Installing from a source is a hectic task and is too difficult. If anything goes wrong, it will make the system more complex and lead me to reinstall, as Python is a mess in its nutshell.
Is there any way I could install it easily?
Thanks

By visiting the link in the error, it looks like it will not install via ppa. Is there any other possibility?

[image]

Comment: You can use Anaconda to set up a virtual environment for Python 3.7 https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi this one worked. I had to installed complete anaconda package to get it working. Thanks

Comment: Did you read https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa where you'll see only LTS releases are supported; 23.10 is **not** a LTS release. Your provided details show LTS with one exception (*vivid*) which was written about back in 2015 & the result was (due workload) only LTS releases would be supported.

Comment: @guiverc i know this fact. But i was asking for any possibility. The conda solved this for me. Now I do not need a standalone installation

Comment: By the way, if you want to save some space, you can remove Anaconda and install Miniconda https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/. It only installs the packages you need, but nothing more

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks for the suggestion. I have switched to miniconda as I was only concerned about the python 3.7 installation. You could paste it as answer and I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: the PPA holds only release files up to Jammy. And due to that, newer release of Ubuntu are not supported. You could try to install from an older release - if you know what you are doing and if you are aware of the risks.

Except this, Python 3.7 is end of life and without support since late June 2023. So you most likely don't want to use it anymore.

Comment: So, there is no way i could install it on 23.10?

Comment: I should still be possible to compile yourself, which is fairly easy for Python. However, the recommendation _not_ to use any Python version which is end of life still applies.

Comment: you are right about the end of life thing but I have a whole project depending on it that was created days back. switching to newer versions of tensoeflow is not easy for me. I have got the thing working using miniconda as suggested by Archisman in the comment.